# Ninject: Injecting a dependency that is also injected in another injected dependency?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

First let me say that I don't have a lot of leeway into how this is implemented, so please keep the "you're doing it wrong" comments to minimum. Thanks.

I have two classes that define read and write operations. Lets call that IReaders and IWriters. Both of them inject a base "data access layer" called IQueryBuilder which is a simple abstraction backed by and entity framework context. All of this is inside a WebAPI implementation hence the generic "Parameterless Constructor" exception.

So lets say you have your writer:

```
public class Writer : IWriter {
    private readonly IQueryBuilder _qb;
    public Writer(IQueryBuilder qb){
        _qb = qb;
    }
}
```

And a Reader:

```
public class Reader: IReader {
    private readonly IQueryBuilder _qb
    public Reader(IQueryBuilder qb){
        _qb = qb;
    }
}
```

Now lets say I want to use Reader inside of Writer:

```
public class Writer : IWriter {
    private readonly IQueryBuilder _qb;
    private readonly IReader _r;
    public Writer(IQueryBuilder qb, IReader r){
        _qb = qb;
        _r = r;
    }
}
```

As you can see the IQuerybuilder is injected into both the new Writer and the injected Reader in this case. The actual code is obviously quite a bit more complex, but long story short when doing this ninject throws a 'parametersless constructor' exception.

So my question is two fold: 1) is there any way to do this without changing the structure of the classes, i.e scoping or something? 2) What would be the appropriate way to go about doing this?

I'm guessing you could use the "WhenInjectedInto" extension?

Comment: Can you post your bindings?

Comment: I could but the real code has several dozen separate bindings, different names, etc. As I mentioned in the comment in response to Brandon Minnicks answer, everything works perfectly until I try to inject the "reader" into the "writer" when they share a dependency (IQueryBuilder) I tried to simplify the question to an example that more or less shows the structure of the dependencies.

Comment: a) What does your bindings look like for IWriter and IReader b) what's your constructor look like for your api controller?

Comment: The bindings are simple, just like Bind<IReader>().To<Reader>(), nothing fancy. Although, I'm pretty sure that's not the issue at this point. At first, when I posted this question, it seemed as though this was some sort of cyclical dependency issue or something. But as I indicated in my comments on Mr Minnicks response below I no longer believe that is the case. This should be working. So I don't think this question can be answered without posting all of the code, which is way too much to be posting here. If anything this discussion has showed me where not to look for an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `parameterless constructor` exceptions do not come from Ninject. Ever. I guess you're using ASP.NET MVC or WebAPI. In that case, AFAIR, this exception also only occurs when Ninject is not properly configured as a container.
Many questions regarding this on SO.

Second, yes, Ninject features several different scoping mechanisms, amongst them [`InRequestScope`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope) for web or WCF projects (given the right extensions..) as well as "build your own" with [`InScope`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes). Again, there's a lot of questions regarding this topic already on SO.

Given the lack of detail in your question it's impossible to give a precise answer.

Comment: I know parameterless constructor exceptions do not come from Ninject and you are correct  I am using WebAPI. That said, everything is currently InRequestScope & all dependencies are properly configured in Ninject and function independently on their own. It's only when I attempt to inject one class that shares a dependency with the class in which it is injected do I see this error. The inner exception is empty in this case.

Pardon the lack of detail I perhaps improperly assumed this might be an issue that would be easily solved. Should this be working under normal circumstances otherwise?

Comment: The more I am thinking about this the more I am realizing this "should" be working. The code is already doing this in several places for other dependencies so perhaps I am focusing on the wrong issue here.

Comment: @Brandon I agree. I'm pretty sure that exception cannot happen if WebAPI is asking Ninject to resolve dependencies. So I'm pretty certain that the integration of Ninject into your project ist faulty.